# Unable to print python dictionary in IDLE

Tags: python

I am trying to print a dictionary value after deleting few key-value. Below code works in **Pycharm** but throwing error when i execute the same in **IDLE** it throws error. please, guide.

```
**users={'John':'Active',
       'Joseph':'Inactive',
       'Reeta':'Inactive'}
for del_user, status in users.copy().items():
    if status=='Inactive':
        del users[del_user] 
        print(del_user)
print(users) **
```

[PyCharm Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv6Z5.png)

[IDLE output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68VZD.png)

Comment: You didn't include the whole syntax error message. works fine for me.

Comment: Try inputting the last line separately.

Comment: Hi Mateen Ulhaq.. Yes it works when I printed the last line separately. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users={'John':'Active',
       'Joseph':'Inactive',
       'Reeta':'Inactive'}
for del_user, status in users.copy().items():
    if status=='Inactive':
        del users[del_user] 
        print(del_user)
print(users)
```

Above code is working fine on IDLE.
Crosscheck that you are giving proper indentation and not adding **.
If might cause if you copy the code from somewhere.

Comment: I printed the last line separately, it works now. Thank you

Comment: mark answer useful please

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the fact that you added asterisks. The program will work in pycharm even without asterisks. Here is the code:

```
    users={'John':'Active',
   'Joseph':'Inactive',
   'Reeta':'Inactive'}
   for del_user, status in users.copy().items():
    if status=='Inactive':
     del users[del_user] 
     print(del_user)
```

print(users)

If the problem still persists in you IDLE, check out the version of IDLE you have. If you want, I will send the code:

```
    import sys
    print (sys.version)
```